# How can I send parameter to alamofire in Swift ios

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I want to send this parameter

```
   {Id:1,
    Comment:{Content:'comment 1'}
   }
```

I wrote this

```
   var content = "comment 1"
   let content: [String : String] = ["Content":"\(content)"] 
   let params: [String : AnyObject]=["Comment":"\(content)", "Id":"123"]
```

but not work

Comment: what error are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

ok My question is true but when my content is numbers

my parameter has a "Optional()" because of that ı get error now ı fixed it like that

```
var content = "comment 1"
let content: [String : String] = ["Content": content] 
let params: [String : AnyObject]=["Comment": content, "Id":"123"]
```

it is work very well

Answer (score 0):

You have `var content` and `let content`. You can't do this. Maybe its the problem. Try it:

```
let contents = ["Content":"comment 1"] 
let params = ["Comment":"\(contents)", "Id":"123"]
println(params) //prints: [Comment: [Content: comment 1], Id: 123]
Alamofire.request(.POST, "http://example.com/post", parameters: params)
```

Comment: this is also not work for me

Comment: Detail "not work".. Show error, give us more details